# Pandas multi index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I currently have a pandas multi index of this structure(with ticker and field being the indices):

```
                                             value
ticker            field                       
DE0001141174 Govt CASH_FLOW_DATE    2000-11-21
                  CASH_FLOW_AMOUNT       51250
                  PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT       1e+06
DE0001141232 Govt CASH_FLOW_DATE    2000-05-17
                  CASH_FLOW_AMOUNT       45000
                  PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT           0
                  CASH_FLOW_DATE    2001-05-17
                  CASH_FLOW_AMOUNT       45000
                  PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT           0
                  CASH_FLOW_DATE    2002-05-17
                  CASH_FLOW_AMOUNT       45000
                  PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT       1e+06
DE0001141380 Govt CASH_FLOW_DATE    2002-08-18
                  CASH_FLOW_AMOUNT     67808.2
                  PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT           0
                  CASH_FLOW_DATE    2003-08-18
                  CASH_FLOW_AMOUNT       45000
                  PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT           0
                  CASH_FLOW_DATE    2004-08-18
                  CASH_FLOW_AMOUNT       45000
                  PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT           0
                  CASH_FLOW_DATE    2005-08-18
                  CASH_FLOW_AMOUNT       45000
                  PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT           0
                  CASH_FLOW_DATE    2006-08-18
                  CASH_FLOW_AMOUNT       45000
                  PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT       1e+06
```

And i want it to be transformed into a structure like this with the ticker and CASH_FLOW_DATE being the indices:

```
ticker              CASH_FLOW_DATE  CASH_FLOW_AMOUNT    PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT          
DE0001141174 Govt   2000-11-21      51250               1e+06
DE0001141232 Govt   2000-05-17      45000               0   
                    2001-05-17      45000               0
                    2002-05-17      45000               1e+06
DE0001141380 Govt   2002-08-18      67808.2             0
                    2003-08-18      45000               0
                    2004-08-18      45000               0
                    2005-08-18      45000               0
                    2006-08-18      45000               0
```

I guess the problem is that python/pandas has no way to naturally recognize that the two rows below 'CASH_FLOW_DATE' are related to that value.
I guess I could do it with a lot of ugly loops, but I was wondering if there is a more pythonic way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for new level of index which is appended by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to original index and then call [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount(), append=True)
df = df['value'].unstack(level=1, fill_value=0).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
field             ticker CASH_FLOW_AMOUNT CASH_FLOW_DATE PRINCIPAL_AMOUNT
0      DE0001141174 Govt            51250     2000-11-21            1e+06
1      DE0001141232 Govt            45000     2000-05-17                0
2      DE0001141232 Govt            45000     2001-05-17                0
3      DE0001141232 Govt            45000     2002-05-17            1e+06
4      DE0001141380 Govt          67808.2     2002-08-18                0
5      DE0001141380 Govt            45000     2003-08-18                0
6      DE0001141380 Govt            45000     2004-08-18                0
7      DE0001141380 Govt            45000     2005-08-18                0
8      DE0001141380 Govt            45000     2006-08-18            1e+06
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, that doest the job (after again setting it to multi index with df.set_index(['ticker', 'field'], inplace=True) )

Comment: I meant df.set_index(['ticker', 'CASH_FLOW_DATE'], inplace=True)